# Header is not allowing <span> to align in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a css header that is not allowing me to align a text in the same line using . I imagine there is a weird default to the header that doesnt allow me to do this how do i prevent the default or what else can i use instead?

HTML

```
h3>Size:</h3>
<?php echo "<span class='sP'>".$pSize ."</span><br>"?>
```

CSS

```
h3{
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
color: #7C7C7C;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}

.sP{
color: #7C7C7C;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be the answer you are looking for - Just put `display:inline-block`. I have put a working sample with the answer.please try this, if there is any issue please do ask.

```css
h3{
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
color: #7C7C7C;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
display:inline-block;
}

.sP{
color: #7C7C7C;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<h3>Size:</h3>
<span class='sP'>hi</span><br>
```

Comment: Yeah that did the job :)

Comment: Glad i could be some help, you can get the same result if you put - `display:block;float:left`, but `display:inline-block` is good for alignment and all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `<span>` in `<h3>` tags as header takes the full width.

```
<h3>Size:
   <?php echo "<span class='sP'>".$pSize ."</span><br>"?>
</h3>
```

Comment: It does work but data/text in $pSize becomes the same header as Size:

Comment: @LukeDS :  Then you can write css to change font size of span.

Answer (score 0):

Heading elements (h1-h6) are block level elements so that's why you specifically need to set them display: inline-block in order to display something next to them.

```css
h1 { display: inline-block }
span { display: inline-block }
```

```html
<h1>Hello, i'm a big fat heading</h1>
<span>Look at me, i'm a little 'ol span</span>
```

Comment: Thanks it did the job.